# Как установить один exe файл из другого в C#

Tags: c#

Нашел метод `Procces.Start();` но это немножко не то что мне надо. Значит сейчас у меня есть 2 .exe файла, один из них это красивое окошко, другой это консольное приложение Windows. Сейчас я тоскаю с собой 2 файла и в оконном приложение запускаю консольное. Можно ли как-то убрать консольное приложение в оконное, чтобы остался один файл и установка консольного была из оконного. Надеюсь понятно, что я хочу.

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не написать инсталлятор? Другой файл _можно_ спрятать в ресурсы, но потом вам нужно вытащить его и сохранить на диск, а на то, что текущий каталог будет доступен для записи, рассчитывать нельзя.

Comment: Вам нужен просто запуск консольного из оконного?

Comment: @Zergatul, да, из оконного консольное.

Comment: консольное тоже на c# написано?

Comment: @Zergatul, да, и консольное, и оконное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавляете ехе-файл к проекту оконного приложения.
2. Смотрите свойства ехе-файла в `Solution Explorer`, меняете `Build Action` на `Embedded Resource`.

Следующий код для оконного приложения:

```
byte[] bytes;
// извлекаем embed resource в массив байт
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowApp.EmbedExe.exe"))
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

// загружаем сборку
var asm = Assembly.Load(bytes);
// запускаем метод точки входа с параметром null
asm.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { null });
```

В вашем случае ресурс будет иметь другое имя, поправите под себя. Что бы посмотреть список имен всех ресурсов, можете вызвать:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. При отладке приложения происходит вылет на строке: `asm.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { null });`
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Какой exception?

Comment: InnerException {"Запуск второго цикла сообщения в единичном потоке является недопустимой операцией. Вместо этого используйте Form.ShowDialog."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: Попробуйте запустить в другом потоке, и выставить ему ApartmentState методом SetApartmentState (если понадобится).

Comment: Я так понимаю, что этот exe будет запускаться в отдельном потоке в данном приложении. А как его можно скопировать например в папку D:\\1\ чтобы потом запустить через Process.Start(); и чтобы этот exe был новым процессом.
Вот какой код получился: `new Thread(() => asm.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { null })).Start();`

Comment: Попробовал так:
`File.AppendAllText("test.exe", bytes.ToString());`
Но файл test.exe не запускается, выбивает ошибку, что версия файла не совместима с версией Windows

Comment: `AppendAllText` сделано для текста, а не для бинарных файлов. Используйте `File.WriteAllBytes`, тогда будет работать.

Comment: Все заработало, огромное спасибо!